# Error using plot Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab.When I tried to import data file and plot it ,it showed the error "Error using plot Not enough input arguments".I have used the following code.

```
filename = '/home/mydata.dat';
delimiter = '\t';
formatSpec = '%s%s%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
datacell= textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter,  'ReturnOnError', false);
Time=datacell{1};
iv1=datacell{2};
plot(Time,iv1);
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: You're trying to plot cells, `plot` rather uses arrays. I also suspect the cells contain strings, also not good for plotting.

Comment: Could you give the contents (or a sample) of the mydata.dat file?

Comment: What is the content of datacell?

Answer (score 0):

Your `formatSpec` has strings, i.e. `%s%s`? If so, that's a problem. You will need to convert the string into a number before plotting.

You can convert strings to numbers two different ways as shown below. The code is on my [Saturn Fiddle](https://saturnapi.com/artw/convert-string-to-number) for you to test.

```
% Welcome to SaturnAPI!
% Start collaborating with MATLAB-Octave fiddles and accomplish more.
% Start your script below these comments.

str2num ("3.141596")

str2num (["1, 2, 3"; "4, 5, 6"])
```